# Автонажатие отправки формы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как сделать автонажатие на input type. Знаю, что надо через js, но как?

Comment: не так написал,нужно сделать так чтобы через каждые например 5 секунд нажимал кнопку input type на другом сайте(не для спама если что))

Comment: тогда javascript тут особо ни при чём.
Надеюсь, что в самом деле не для спама.
curl в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

отправка формы скриптом?

```
form.submit()
```